# C++ undefined reference to template member function

Tags: c++, templates, reference, undefined

```
//Forward declaration
class MyType;

class Factory{
    template<class T>
    static T* CreateObject(T& newOb){
         return &newOb;
    }
    //Other non template functions 
}

//In main (error causing line)
MyType tmptype;
MyType* newMyType = Factory::CreateObject<MyType>(tmptype);
```

This code causes this error:
undefined reference to `MyType* Factory::CreateObject(MyType&)'

I also get this warning:
warning: auto-importing has been activated without --enable-auto-import specified on the command line

Additionally, it still doesn't work if I use an int type, which rules out the possibility of the type not being included properly.

Comment: you're missing a template<class T> before class Factory

Comment: Also missing a closing semicolon on the class definition.

Comment: Please post code that reproduces the problem, not code with random other compilation errors...

Answer (score 1):

The function takes a reference, so you need to pass it a variable of which the compiler may take an address.

```
class Factory{
public:
    template<class T>
    static T* CreateObject(T& newOb){
        return &newOb;
    }
    //Other non template functions
};

class MyType {};

int main() {
    MyType a;
    MyType* newMyType = Factory::CreateObject<MyType>(a);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, thats not my actual code. In my mock up i forgot to include public! The real scope in the file is public

Comment: @RaptorIV Are you getting the same error? I copied the two lines from the code that compiles with g++ on MacOS.

Comment: yes, same exact error no matter what I change. I'm also getting warnings about auto-importing if that means anything

Comment: @RaptorIV That is strange. What compiler do you use? Could you copy-paste the code from the answer, and see if it compiles?

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined MyType. If you are passing the Factory class the object that you want to create then you need to define the type that you are passsing. Without passing in the type of object that the factory class is not possible to create one! So You MyType should be either a typedef for primitive or struct/class that defines your own data type.

Ideally,

```
class MyType{
     //Some data structure or type that you want to use.
};
```

and

```
class Factory{
public:
    template<class T>
    static T* CreateObject(T& newOb){
        return &newOb;
    }
    //Other non template functions
}
```

Would allow your factory class to create an object of your own type.

Comment: the type MyType is defined, just excluded from the example.

Comment: You should include a forward class declaration at least in your example then - or an include or comment to show that.

Comment: In my example it seems to work perfectly fine. The only thing that you might be missing is that you declared MyType in another header file and did not include it in the file that has the main() function. Can you provide the entire thing that you had tried?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. Your function calling syntax is wrong. All you need to do is call `Factory::CreateObject(tmptype);`

You need not instantiate a templated function the way you do for templated classes.

Comment: His code is not wrong, at least not in that particular spot. It is OK to specify the type explicitly, even when the compiler can figure it out.